# Selective dependencies in Gradle

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I'm setting up a multi-project Gradle build to replace an existing Ant build, where all the sub projects have their own `build.gradle` file in which the sub-project's dependencies are defined.

My sub projects all have their own dependencies, and there's a small subset of those (all 3rd party jars) that are only needed as a compile-time dependency in all the sub projects, like Maven's `provided` scope. (I have already found how I can create a configuration in Gradle that behaves like that.)

However, since this is a small set of jars, and they're the same for all sub projects, I'd like to extract the knowledge of which jars are provided out of the individual sub projects's dependency lists, and into the main build script, somehow. I want this so that developers who add a sub project to the system, don't need to know about which dependencies are provided and which aren't.

In other words, I would like to have a configuration that behaves as `provided` for a specific list of dependencies, and as `compile` for all the others.

I have this in the main `build.gradle`:

```
ext.providedDependencies = [
    "org.apache.log4j:log4j:1.2.16",
    "joda-time:joda-time:2.0"
]

...

configurations { myconfig }
```

And one or more of the sub projects have a `build.gradle` like this:

```
dependencies {
    myconfig "org.apache.log4j:log4j:1.2.16"
    myconfig "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2"
}
```

Then I want the behavior to be like this:

```
dependencies {
    provided "org.apache.log4j:log4j:1.2.16"
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2"
}
```

Because log4j is in `ext.providedDependencies`, and commons-lang3 isn't. I want this same behavior for all of my subprojects.

---

I have tried to (partially) implement `myconfig` like this:

```
subprojects {
    dependencies {
        configurations.myconfig.dependencies.each { dep ->
            if (providedDependencies.contains(dep)) {
                compile dep
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But that does not work, because it turns out that `configurations.myconfig.dependencies` is empty (I don't understand why, though). In other words, the dependencies don't get added.

I also tried this, but here the opposite happens: all the dependencies are added, including those that are in the list of provided dependencies.

```
subprojects {
    dependencies {
        compile(configurations.myconfig) {
            providedDependencies.each { exclude it }
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know how I can make this work, or if there is a different, better way to achieve what I want.

---

**EDIT** Partially re-written for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ext{
    dependencies = [
                    "dependencyGroup:dependencyName:dependencyVersion",
                    "dependency2Group:dependency2Name:dependency2Version"
    ]
}

subprojects{
    dependencies {
        provided dependencies
    }
    configurations {
        compile.exclude group: 'dependencyGroup'
        compile.exclude group: 'dependency2Group'
    }
}
```

In the above example, we have defined a list of dependencies with the name `dependencies`.

**EDIT** -- We are excluding the dependencies from the compile configuration if they need to be provided. This means that all even if a subproject adds a dependency that you want to be provided as compile, it won't happen.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; maybe my question was unclear though. It's not my sub-projects that should be provided, it's 3rd party libraries (such as log4j).

Comment: @jqno Sorry if I wasn't clear. I have added an explanation below the code sample. Hopefully that makes it clearer. Let me know of any issues.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now. It's not really an answer to my question though: my question applies to *all* sub-projects, and to a subset of all the dependencies. I'll update my question to clarify.

Comment: What defines whether a subproject should have them as compile or provided dependencies?

Comment: I have a list `ext.providedDependencies = [...]` that enumerates them.

Comment: I think there may be a misunderstanding around this sentence (which is unclear to me): "I would like to have a configuration that behaves as provided for a specific list of dependencies, and as compile for all the others."

Comment: If you have a hard coded list I am not sure I understand how this doesn't help you? You have that list of dependencies. If the project is in your providedDependencies list, then add the dependencies to the provided configuration. If not, add them to the compile configuration. That way, the subproject build.gradle doesn't need to do anything. These dependencies are already added. Sorry if I am not understanding, but that sounds like what you were aiming for to me?

Comment: I see the confusion. What I want, is a 90° rotation, so to speak. I don't want to differentiate on the subprojects, I want to differentiate on the dependencies themselves. So for example I want "provided" if the dependency is log4j, and "compiled" if it's anything else, and I want that for *all* subprojects. I'm sorry my question was confusing; I've edited it to make it more clear.

Comment: The reason for this is that many developers may add new subprojects, and I don't want them to need to know whether log4j needs to be "provided" or not, because that's likely to be error-prone.

Comment: Ahh ok I see. So you want to safeguard against someone putting a compile dependency in a subproject if you have defined it in the provided dependencies list?

Comment: @jqno Made an edit. Still not quite what you were looking for I don't think, but it's a step closer. Will keep thinking.

Comment: @BenGreen That's it, actually! `configurations { compile.exclude ... }` does what I need, while putting the exclude in `dependencies`, like in the final example in my question, didn't.